# How can i fix that some of my images in gallery are not showing at all?

Tags: php, html, refresh

enter code here some of my pictures are showing only after page refresh.
In browser console are errors - get ... image url... 503 or 403 error
Could someone help me please ?

my htacces code -

```
 RewriteEngine on
RewriteBase /

RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^id=8$
RewriteRule ^albumgallery.php$ https://www.website.com/blabla? [L,R=301]
RewriteRule ^blabla/?$ /albumgallery.php?id=8&loop=no [L]    

RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^.*/index\.php 
RewriteRule ^(.*)index.php$ /$1 [R=301,L] 

RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^.*/index 
RewriteRule ^(.*)index$ /$1 [R=301,L]    

RewriteCond %{ENV:HTTPS} !on
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]

#Exclusion
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/(images|images/.*)$
#End exclusion
```

and this is code for image

```
<a title="<?php echo $gimagenonumber ?>" href="images/gupload/<?php echo $gimage; ?>" data-lightbox="ourClass"><img alt="<?php echo $gimagenonumber ?>" title="<?php echo $gimagenonumber ?>" class="horizontals" src="/images/gcatch/<?php echo $gimage ?>"/></a>
```

in console is - Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 503 () - for all unloaded images

i've also noticed that it is doing on whole site when you press ctr+f5 few times in row

Comment: try posting some code or screenshots

Comment: i did post some code

Answer (score 0):

Are you working on local machine ? Please check your .htaccess file or move your pitures into a subfolder

Comment: Show us your .htaccess file content

Answer (score 0):

**Try this one**
*After*

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
```

**Add**

```
#Exclusion
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/(images|images/.*)$
#End exclusion
```

Comment: could you have a look at the code please ? i updated it... seems to me - page finishes loading before all images are loaded